# Unable to detect error while using PhotonView.isMine method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PhotonPlayerSetup : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, IInRoomCallbacks
{
    private PhotonView PV;

    void Awake()
    {
        PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if(PV.isMine)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

While using above mentioned code this error appears:

> "PhotonView does not contain a definition for `isMine` and no
> accessible extension method `isMine` accepting a first argument of
> type 'PhotonView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for choosing Photon!

`PhotonView.isMine` from PUN Classic was renamed to `PhotonView.IsMine` in PUN 2.
Make sure to check out the [Migration Notes](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/migration-notes).